# Concat Arrays on all fields MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Imagine I have this collection:

```
{
  id: 1,
  b: { 
   "field1": ['foo'],
   "field2": ['bar']
  }
}
{
  id: 2,
  b: { 
   "field2": ["foobar"],
   "field3": ["foofoo"]
  }
}
```

And I want to obtain a new collection with MongoDB:

```
{
 id: 1,
 b_grouped: ['foo', 'bar']
}
{
 id: 2,
 b_grouped: ["foobar", "foofoo"]
}
```

I don't know all the name of the fields in the documents, anyone would have an idea of how to perform something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { "$project": { "b_grouped": { $concatArrays: ["$b.*"] } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Your sample data is not valid JSON. Are these two documents or just one?

Comment: I got confused while writing it, I fixed it and it is actually two documents

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try,

- [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) input `b` as a array after converting from object to array using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html), this will convert object in "k" (key), "v" (value) format array of object,
- [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to concat `initialValue` *($$value)* of `$raduce` and array of `b` object's field *$$this.v*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      b_grouped: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$b" },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: ["$$this.v", "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GxlvJy-aXhO)